# associating image path with title on the front end

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I'd like to display images and their respective titles when someone mouses over the matching Class year.

With help, I've been able to display just the images based on class year... but now I need the titles underneath. With PHP and database, I can easily do this fetch from database fields... but I'm working solely with Javascript here.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">     
        var classes = {
            2011: [
                "/name1.jpg", "name 1",
                "/name2.jpg", "name 2"],
            2012: [
                "/name3.jpg", "name 3",
                "/name4.jpg", "name 4"],
            2013: [
                "/name5.jpg", "name 5",
                "/name6.jpg", "name 6"]
            };

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

          $('li').on('mouseover', function(e){
            $('#overlay').empty();
            var title = $('<h2>');
            title.text('Class of ' +  e.target.id);
            $('#overlay').append(title);
            $(classes[e.target.id]).each(function(idx, entry){
              var img = $('<img/>');
              img.attr('src', entry);
              $('#overlay').append(img);
            });         
          });         
        });

    </script>

</head> 
<body>              
    <ul id="classes">
        <br>
        <li id="2011">Class of 2011</li>
        <li id="2012">Class of 2012</li>
        <li id="2013">Class of 2013</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see you are already using jQuery. You might want to take a look at the [`tooltip()`](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) method to show them titles! ||||||| After setting the `src` attribute of the images, also set their `title` attribute, and then, once you appended the images, do the following: `$.each($('#overlay img').tooltip();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are oddly structured. You might should change them to something like

```
var classes = {
    2011: [
        {src:"/name1.jpg", title:"name 1"},
        {src:"/name2.jpg", title:"name 2"}
    ],
    2012: …
}
```

With your current structure, the loop should be this:

```
var arr = classes[e.target.id];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2)
     $('#overlay').append(
         $('<img/>', {'src': arr[i], 'alt': arr[i+1]}),
         $('<p/>', {'text': arr[i+1]}) // or something
     );
```